# Ошибка cd: no such file or directory

Tags: git-bash

возможно ошибка в том, что неправильно указан путь, папка находится: D:\Open Server\OpenServer\domains\mm

[image: скрин]

как правильно указать нужно?

Answer (score 1):

У вас там пробел в пути. Экранируйте его с помощью обратного слеша:

```
cd Open\ Server/OpenServer/domains/mm
```

Или указывайте путь в кавычках:

```
cd "Open Server/OpenServer/domains/mm"
```

На будущее:

- старайтесь использовать пути без пробелов, будет меньше мороки.
- В консоли активно используйте автоподстановку с помощью Tab – она бы подсказала вам нужное написание

Comment: а почему domaind? ведь конечный путь D:\Open Server\OpenServer\domains\mm   а нужно так? cd Open\ Server/Open\ Server/domain/mm и как использовать Tab?

Comment: @Fin это опечатка

Comment: @Fin ну что, помогло?

Comment: Можно написать путь в кавычках

Comment: @Alex78191 кстати, да.

Comment: @Alex78191 спасибо, что напомнили. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Fin помогло только изменение пути на более короткий) d/mm,  подозреваю, что теперь настройки расположения папки для запуска Open Server тоже надо будет менять. но сейчас другая ошибка. связана ли она с этим или надо другую тему создавать) вообщем, создался репозиторий в github, но в консоли после команды $ git commit -m 'first save'  сообщение: Please tell me who you are git  config --global user.email you@example.com' и user.name 'your Name' to set your account's default identity.Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.  fatal: empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed

Comment: @Fin про это можно задать новый вопрос. Но все ясно и так: нужна первоначальная конфигурация. Выполните инструкции, задайте свое имя и почту. Они необходимы для коммита.